# Vue.js is it possible to get '@' sign resolved during runtime?

Tags: javascript, compilation, vuejs2, runtime

In my template I am trying to display divs with images as a background.
My template is:

```
<template>
  <section>
    <div 
      :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + image2 + ')' }"
      class="circular"/>
    <div 
      :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url('+ image +')' }"
      class="dummy" />
  </section>
</template>
```

and the values of `image` and `image2` are set as below:

```
<script>
...
import { mapState, mapMutations } from "vuex";
export default {
  name: "Apollo",
  data() {
    return {
      image2:
        "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-8PfnHfgrH4I/TylX2v8pTMI/AAAAAAAAJJ4/TICBoSEI57o/s1600/search_by_image_image.png",
      image: "~@/assets/icon_aboutYou_color.svg"
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
...
</script>
```

The style section is:

```
<style scoped>
.dummy {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
}
.circular {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
}
</style>
```

And the first div has its background image displayed properly. In fact it is a copy of this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/89af0se9/1/) I found during my research on the web.
The second does not.

**My guess is that the `@` sign in the `image` path can not be resolved during runtime and can be only resolved once, during compilation phase.**
As an argument I use the below example:

If I add third div to my template, with the same way given `src` as in the background `url`:

```
<div><img 
  src="~@/assets/icon_aboutYou_color.svg" 
  alt="test"></div>
```

The image here is displayed properly. When I am inspecting the web page source that is generated in Chrome, I see that div with `image` set as background by `inline` statement looks like this:

```
<div data-v-74161b7f="" class="dummy" style="background-image: url("~@/assets/icon_aboutYou_color.svg");"></div>
```

while the `img` looks like *compiled* or *resolved* to some other value:

```
<div data-v-74161b7f=""><img data-v-74161b7f="" src="img/icon_aboutYou_color.2917b0e8.svg" alt="test"></div>
```

which is exactly what I would like to achieve using `inline style ={}` statement.

I can also get it working using predefined classes:

```
.about-icon {
  @include icon;
  background-image: url("~@/assets/icon_aboutYou_color.svg");
}
```

**The question is:**
Is it true that `@` sign is resolved during *compilation* phase and cannot be resolved during runtime?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to webpack alias that are e.g. defined in the webpack.base.conf.js its true. They are defined during runtime and will not change afterwards.
You can use the webpack define plugin to replace a string like **myAssetPath** to your asset path in the webpack config. You can access it in your data elements then.

If you need to resolve @ during runtime, I would recommend using a REST call requesting the needed url on page load to store it in the store or window object. Then you can engineer your custom url just by writing :style="baseURL + 'whatever you need'". (baseURL needs to point to your URL)
Or you can simply proxy requests using your middleware.

Comment: "_They are defined during runtime_" you probably meant _build_ time?

Comment: @ghybs They get defined during build time, thus they are defined during runtime. Perhaps a language problem? I am afraid, I am not a native english speaker.